# VBA apply to certain range

Tags: excel, vba

I have following code that allowed me to select multiple items under data validation. However, I have two set of data validation and I only want this code to apply on Range("K41:K60, K73:K107) Please advised. Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler


On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler


If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler


If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then


Else
Application.EnableEvents = False
newVal = Target.Value
Application.Undo
oldVal = Target.Value
Target.Value = newVal
 If oldVal = "" Then

 Else
 If newVal = "" Then

 Else
 Target.Value = oldVal _
   & ", " & newVal


 End If
 End If
 End If


 exitHandler:
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you only want this code triggered when a cell in that range is changed? If so, perhaps amend this line as below

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("K41:K60, K73:K107")) Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I have second drop down list in H3, but I don't want it to be able to select multiple items which above code does.

Comment: If your code can do avoid H3 to select multiple items in the list, where should I insert the code? I am new to macro or coding, I found the code online. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow. Can you explain a little more about what you are doing?